# Nintendo Switch - Joy-Con Single mode for Fifa 18

Tags: nintendo-switch, fifa-18

I've read that there is a possibility to play Fifa 18 on Nintendo Switch with a single joy con controller out of a pair. Basically sharing Joy-Con left and Joy-Con right between two players, thus using one pair of Joy-Con to play with two players.

EA is noting about that feature here: https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/fifa/fifa-18/play-fifa-18-built-for-nintendo-switch/ - but I could not yet find any explanation how to make this work (neither online, nor by try and error with the Switch console).

Can someone explain how to use this feature with Nintendo Switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, talking to EA Support has led the way. It is basically not a Fifa 18 specific feature, but a general feature of Nintendo switch.

It is about configuring Joy Con Pairing. There are different modes and one of them is "Solo horizontal grip".

To configure one Joy-Con out of a pair for this, you take the Joy Con and press the "SL" and "SR" buttons. These are on the side which connects the Joy Con to the switch console or the controller handheld. So of course "Solo horizontal grip" is only possible with Joy Con taken out of the Switch console or the controller handheld.

So the difference in pairing is that for dual joy con pairing you need to press "L" and "R" on the Joy Cons and for single joy con you need to press "SL" and "SR" on one of the Joy Cons.

Nintendo gives explanation here: http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22416